# Why is optimizer.minimize not working if we pass loss as tf.constant?

Tags: tensorflow

I simply have `train = optimizer.minimize(loss = tf.constant(4,dtype="float32"))` Line of code that i change before everything is working.

Why it is giving error ? Because documentation say it can be tensor [Here is Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam#minimize)

```
W = tf.Variable([0.5],tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([0.1],tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
discounted_reward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[4,], name="discounted_reward")
linear_model = W*x + b

squared_delta = tf.square(linear_model - y)
print(squared_delta)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_delta*discounted_reward)
print(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss = tf.constant(4,dtype="float32"))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

for i in range(3):
    sess.run(train,{x:[1,2,3,4],y:[0,-1,-2,-3],discounted_reward:[1,2,3,4]})

print(sess.run([W,b]))
```

---

I really need this thing to work. In this particular example we can have other ways to solve it but i need it to work as my actual code can do this only

---

Error is

```
> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
> for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
> ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_7:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_8:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_9:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_10:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_11:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_12:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_13:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_14:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_15:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_16:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_17:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_18:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_19:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_20:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_21:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_22:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_23:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_24:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_25:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_26:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_27:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_28:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_29:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_30:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_31:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_32:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_33:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_34:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_35:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_36:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_37:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_38:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_39:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_40:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_41:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss
> Tensor("Const_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The loss is a constant; it can't be optimized. The optimizer's job is to figure out via gradient descent how the model variables (W, b) should be changed to minimize the loss. Here, because the loss is constant, the variables have no influence on the loss. As such, there is no gradient.

Comment: @xdurch0 I agree that this loss function wont work.

Comment: @xdurch0 It will not teach neural net as expected. That is different problem ( i will be sending different value every time in my real code ). But WHY IS IT THROWING ERROR ?

Comment: You haven't posted any error.

Comment: @xdurch0 Oops. Sorry. And i updated the ans